# Why using allowframebreaks in beamer bringing up annoying additional blank frame?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, allowframebreaks

I'm using `beamer` for my presentation and I need to add a bibliography for which I need to use the option `allowframebreaks` since I don't know how many frames it will take. However, I'm facing very annoying issue that is one more (empty) frame at the end is coming up without any text, is there anyway to suppress that frame?
Here is my code along with .bib file ( I hope there is no copyright or any issue in this regard). I want to list all the references in the .bib file that is why I used `\nocite{*}.`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}  % I add this one to make changes and command the orignal one.
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
\nocite{*}
\vspace{-0.6cm}
%\begin{frame}{References}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES} 
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\scriptsize     % font size 7pt
%\tiny
\bibliography{AlFagera}
\clearpage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The contents of my bibliography file which should be saved as AlFagera.bib is given bellow:

```
@article{_j._????,
  title = {J. {{Kim Vandiver}}, 2.{{003SC}} / 1.{{053J Engineering Dynamics}}, {{Fall}} 2011. ({{MIT OpenCourseWare}}: {{Massachusetts Institute}} of {{Technology}}), {{https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-003sc-engineering-dynamics-fall-2011/}} ({{Accessed March}} 22, 2017). {{License}}: {{Creative}} Commons {{BY}}-{{NC}}-{{SA}}},
  file = {C:\\Users\\SATLLITE\\Zotero\\storage\\DBJSWH93\\MIT2_003SCF11_pset10Sol.pdf}
}

@article{bejan_fundamentals_2002,
  title = {Fundamentals of Exergy Analysis, Entropy Generation Minimization, and the Generation of Flow Architecture},
  volume = {26},
  number = {7},
  journal = {International Journal of Energy Research},
  author = {Bejan, Adrian},
  year = {2002},
  pages = {0--43},
  file = {C:\\Users\\SATLLITE\\Zotero\\storage\\8B7IQV7D\\Bejan-2002-International_Journal_of_Energy_Research.pdf}
}

@article{sunar2015entropy,
  title = {Entropy Generation Rate in a Mechanical System Subjected to a Damped Oscillation},
  volume = {17},
  number = {4},
  journal = {International Journal of Exergy},
  author = {Sunar, M and Sahin, AZ and Yilbas, BS},
  year = {2015},
  pages = {401-411},
  file = {C:\\Users\\SATLLITE\\Zotero\\storage\\EHRPUQUB\\Paper_SSY.pdf}
}

@article{belandria2008positive,
  title = {Positive and Negative Entropy Production in Thermodynamics Systems},
  journal = {arXiv preprint arXiv:0901.0023},
  author = {Belandria, Jos{\'e} Iraides},
  year = {2008}
}

@article{dondapati2014entropy,
  title = {Entropy Generation Minimization ({{EGM}}) to Optimize Mass Flow Rate in Dual Channel Cable-in-Conduit Conductors ({{CICCs}}) Used for Fusion Grade Magnets},
  volume = {89},
  number = {6},
  journal = {Fusion Engineering and design},
  author = {Dondapati, Raja Sekhar and Rao, VV},
  year = {2014},
  pages = {837-846},
  publisher = {{Elsevier}}
}

@article{al2008entropy,
  title = {Entropy Generation Rate during Laser Pulse Heating: {{Effect}} of Laser Pulse Parameters on Entropy Generation Rate},
  volume = {46},
  number = {1},
  journal = {Optics and Lasers in Engineering},
  author = {Al-Qahtani, H and Yilbas, BS},
  year = {2008},
  pages = {27-33},
  publisher = {{Elsevier}}
}

@article{silverberg2007classical,
  title = {Classical Analytical Mechanics and Entropy Production},
  journal = {arXiv preprint physics/0701096},
  author = {Silverberg, J and Widom, A},
  year = {2007}
}

@article{zhang2005maximum,
  title = {Maximum Entropy Spectral Analysis in Vibration Experiment of Vehicle during Accelerating and Decelerating.},
  volume = {24},
  number = {1},
  journal = {Zhendong yu Chongji(J. Vibr. Shock)},
  author = {Zhang, Lijun and Zhang, Tianxia},
  year = {2005},
  pages = {30-32}
}

@article{lakzian2018entropy,
  title = {The Entropy Generation Rate Minimization for a Proposed Air Ejector for the Carpet Industry},
  volume = {53},
  number = {1-2},
  journal = {Meccanica},
  author = {Lakzian, Esmail and Hajian, Masoud and Farahmand, Ali},
  year = {2018},
  pages = {145-159},
  publisher = {{Springer}}
}

@article{goudarzi2015improving,
  title = {Improving Performance of Two-Phase Natural Circulation Loops by Reducing of Entropy Generation},
  volume = {93},
  journal = {Energy},
  author = {Goudarzi, N and Talebi, S},
  year = {2015},
  pages = {882-899},
  publisher = {{Elsevier}}
}

@article{chen2016propagation,
  title = {Propagation and Generation of Acoustic and Entropy Waves across a Moving Flame Front},
  volume = {166},
  journal = {Combustion and Flame},
  author = {Chen, Lin Strobio and Bomberg, Sebastian and Polifke, Wolfgang},
  year = {2016},
  pages = {170-180},
  publisher = {{Elsevier}}
}

@article{peters2003nonlinear,
  title = {Nonlinear {{Damping}} of the'{{Linear}}'{{Pendulum}}},
  journal = {arXiv preprint physics/0306081},
  author = {Peters, Randall D},
  year = {2003}
}
```

Any suggestions, are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add the empty page with the `\clearpage` command.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}  % I add this one to make changes and command the orignal one.


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{_j._????,
  title = {J. {{Kim Vandiver}}, 2.{{003SC}} / 1.{{053J Engineering Dynamics}}, {{Fall}} 2011. ({{MIT OpenCourseWare}}: {{Massachusetts Institute}} of {{Technology}}), {{https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-003sc-engineering-dynamics-fall-2011/}} ({{Accessed March}} 22, 2017). {{License}}: {{Creative}} Commons {{BY}}-{{NC}}-{{SA}}},
  file = {C:\\Users\\SATLLITE\\Zotero\\storage\\DBJSWH93\\MIT2_003SCF11_pset10Sol.pdf}
}

@article{bejan_fundamentals_2002,
  title = {Fundamentals of Exergy Analysis, Entropy Generation Minimization, and the Generation of Flow Architecture},
  volume = {26},
  number = {7},
  journal = {International Journal of Energy Research},
  author = {Bejan, Adrian},
  year = {2002},
  pages = {0--43},
  file = {C:\\Users\\SATLLITE\\Zotero\\storage\\8B7IQV7D\\Bejan-2002-International_Journal_of_Energy_Research.pdf}
}

@article{sunar2015entropy,
  title = {Entropy Generation Rate in a Mechanical System Subjected to a Damped Oscillation},
  volume = {17},
  number = {4},
  journal = {International Journal of Exergy},
  author = {Sunar, M and Sahin, AZ and Yilbas, BS},
  year = {2015},
  pages = {401-411},
  file = {C:\\Users\\SATLLITE\\Zotero\\storage\\EHRPUQUB\\Paper_SSY.pdf}
}

@article{belandria2008positive,
  title = {Positive and Negative Entropy Production in Thermodynamics Systems},
  journal = {arXiv preprint arXiv:0901.0023},
  author = {Belandria, Jos{\'e} Iraides},
  year = {2008}
}

@article{dondapati2014entropy,
  title = {Entropy Generation Minimization ({{EGM}}) to Optimize Mass Flow Rate in Dual Channel Cable-in-Conduit Conductors ({{CICCs}}) Used for Fusion Grade Magnets},
  volume = {89},
  number = {6},
  journal = {Fusion Engineering and design},
  author = {Dondapati, Raja Sekhar and Rao, VV},
  year = {2014},
  pages = {837-846},
  publisher = {{Elsevier}}
}

@article{al2008entropy,
  title = {Entropy Generation Rate during Laser Pulse Heating: {{Effect}} of Laser Pulse Parameters on Entropy Generation Rate},
  volume = {46},
  number = {1},
  journal = {Optics and Lasers in Engineering},
  author = {Al-Qahtani, H and Yilbas, BS},
  year = {2008},
  pages = {27-33},
  publisher = {{Elsevier}}
}

@article{silverberg2007classical,
  title = {Classical Analytical Mechanics and Entropy Production},
  journal = {arXiv preprint physics/0701096},
  author = {Silverberg, J and Widom, A},
  year = {2007}
}

@article{zhang2005maximum,
  title = {Maximum Entropy Spectral Analysis in Vibration Experiment of Vehicle during Accelerating and Decelerating.},
  volume = {24},
  number = {1},
  journal = {Zhendong yu Chongji(J. Vibr. Shock)},
  author = {Zhang, Lijun and Zhang, Tianxia},
  year = {2005},
  pages = {30-32}
}

@article{lakzian2018entropy,
  title = {The Entropy Generation Rate Minimization for a Proposed Air Ejector for the Carpet Industry},
  volume = {53},
  number = {1-2},
  journal = {Meccanica},
  author = {Lakzian, Esmail and Hajian, Masoud and Farahmand, Ali},
  year = {2018},
  pages = {145-159},
  publisher = {{Springer}}
}

@article{goudarzi2015improving,
  title = {Improving Performance of Two-Phase Natural Circulation Loops by Reducing of Entropy Generation},
  volume = {93},
  journal = {Energy},
  author = {Goudarzi, N and Talebi, S},
  year = {2015},
  pages = {882-899},
  publisher = {{Elsevier}}
}

@article{chen2016propagation,
  title = {Propagation and Generation of Acoustic and Entropy Waves across a Moving Flame Front},
  volume = {166},
  journal = {Combustion and Flame},
  author = {Chen, Lin Strobio and Bomberg, Sebastian and Polifke, Wolfgang},
  year = {2016},
  pages = {170-180},
  publisher = {{Elsevier}}
}

@article{peters2003nonlinear,
  title = {Nonlinear {{Damping}} of the'{{Linear}}'{{Pendulum}}},
  journal = {arXiv preprint physics/0306081},
  author = {Peters, Randall D},
  year = {2003}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
\nocite{*}
\vspace{-0.6cm}
%\begin{frame}{References}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES} 
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\scriptsize     % font size 7pt
%\tiny
\bibliography{\jobname}
%\clearpage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: **I cannot believe this !!!** I just copied the bibliography section from thesis where there was a real need for  `\clearpage`