# Empty frame due to `allowframebreaks`

Tags: beamer, spacing, bibtex

The MWE below, after compiling with `pdflatex mwe.tex && bibtex mwe.aux && pdflatex mwe.tex` generates a PDF with 3 pages. 1. the sigh frame, 2. the first of two bibliography frames, and finally a contentless "Bibliography II" frame (i.e. empty page/empty frame).

I am aware that `allowframebreaks` is a terrible idea for actual content and might have is flaws but in this case I'd like to use it nevertheless. **What's the reason for the empty frame** and how to avoid it (apart from changing the content of the bibliography of course ;)?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@article{bornmann2017,
  author="Bornmann, Lutz",
  title="Measuring impact in research evaluations: a thorough discussion of methods for, effects of and problems with impact measurements",
  journal="Higher Education",
  year="2017",
  month=may,
  day="1",
  volume="73",
  number="5",
  pages="775--787",
  issn="1573-174X",
  doi="10.1007/s10734-016-9995-x",
}

@article{meyer2009,
  author = {Meyer, Bertrand and Choppy, Christine and Staunstrup, J{\o}rgen and van Leeuwen, Jan},
  title = {Viewpoint: Research Evaluation for Computer Science},
  journal = {Communications of the ACM},
  volume = {52},
  number = {4},
  month = apr,
  year = {2009},
  issn = {0001-0782},
  pages = {31--34},
  numpages = {4},
  doi = {10.1145/1498765.1498780},
  acmid = {1498780},
  publisher = {ACM},
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
}

@techreport{esposito2018,
  author = {Floriana Esposito and Carlo Ghezzi and Manuel Hermenegildo and Helene Kirchner and Luke Ong},
  title = {Informatics Research Evaluation},
  institution = {Informatics Europe Informatics Europe Informatics Europe Informatics Europe Informatics Europe Informatics Europe Informatics Europe Informatics Europe Informatics Europe Informatics Europe Informatics Europe},
  day = {22},
  month = mar,
  year = {2018},
  url = {http://www.informatics-europe.org/component/phocadownload/},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{sigh}
  \cite{*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[c,allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
  \bibliography{bib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I forgot to mention that I tried playing with the factor of `allowframebreaks` and this can be more or less used as a workaround but since it has to be customized for each case I'd still like to know what triggers it and if a fix is feasible.

I really hope this is not as embarrassing as [the previous version of this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429160) (not mine! ;)

Comment: It wasn't my question, it just popped up when I looked for my problem and I found it quite ironic that there was such an easy fix for it while I am for hours wrestling with this (and .bst hacking)... ;)

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry! Don't know why I assumed it would be yours!

Comment: @samcarter I still think your answer was worthwhile to publish even if it didnt perfectly fit my fundamental question. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: OK, I undeleted my answer -- but I think there will always be edge cases where the content will overflow into the margin instead of being shifted to the next frame

Comment: @samcarter hm, I guess elaborating on why things in "the margin" dont get "shifted" would answer my question. I lack a general understanding on how the `allowframebreaks` option apparently.

Comment: They don't get shifted because page breaks within a bibitem are not allowed. This problem would not happen if it would be normal text instead

Comment: So beamer detects that the content is too large and creates another frame but is not able to actually push the whole entry there? I would have thought it automatically overflows in that case by way of a frame break that is inserted before the entry. But I guess reality is more complicated?

Comment: At the position where the item starts, the frame is not yet full enough, at the next possibility it is too full. That is a complicate situation to solve unless you process the content multiple times

Comment: Understood but "at the next possibility" (after the bibitem I presume) there is nothing else to output but the frame break is inserted anyway(?) That seems to be avoidable at this abstraction level.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that you are instructing the framebreak to happen earlier than usual by setting `allowframebreaks=0.85`. In your case this means that the framebreak is supposed to be somewhere within the 3 bib entry, but bib entries cannot be split across slides.

2 workarounds:

Use the whole frame with `allowframebreaks` or make the framebreak before the third item, e.g.`allowframebreaks=0.75`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@article{bornmann2017,
  author="Bornmann, Lutz",
  title="Measuring impact in research evaluations: a thorough discussion of methods for, effects of and problems with impact measurements",
  journal="Higher Education",
  year="2017",
  month=may,
  day="1",
  volume="73",
  number="5",
  pages="775--787",
  issn="1573-174X",
  doi="10.1007/s10734-016-9995-x",
}

@article{meyer2009,
  author = {Meyer, Bertrand and Choppy, Christine and Staunstrup, J{\o}rgen and van Leeuwen, Jan},
  title = {Viewpoint: Research Evaluation for Computer Science},
  journal = {Communications of the ACM},
  volume = {52},
  number = {4},
  month = apr,
  year = {2009},
  issn = {0001-0782},
  pages = {31--34},
  numpages = {4},
  doi = {10.1145/1498765.1498780},
  acmid = {1498780},
  publisher = {ACM},
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
}

@techreport{esposito2018,
  author = {Floriana Esposito and Carlo Ghezzi and Manuel Hermenegildo and Helene Kirchner and Luke Ong},
  title = {Informatics Research Evaluation},
  institution = {Informatics Europe Informatics Europe Informatics Europe Informatics Europe Informatics Europe},
  day = {22},
  month = mar,
  year = {2018},
  url = {http://www.informatics-europe.org/component/phocadownload/},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{sigh}
  \cite{*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[c,allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
  \bibliography{bib}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[c,allowframebreaks=0.75]{Bibliography}
  \bibliography{bib}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried playing with the factor of `allowframebreaks` but that's a hacky workaround...

Comment: @stefanct I would simply leave out the factor and use the whole sldie

Comment: Sure, that's not the point though because I am interested in the underlying reason.. Of course one can create the same behavior with the default factor (which is 0.9 IIRC). I have edited the MWE accordingly to show that.